# Office Add-in don't works with "asp:"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ms-office

I want to start a function in CodeBehind I read that I just need to add "asp:" so that the C# function is called and not the js but when I add asp to my code the add-in stops working.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txt_OnTextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Can someone please help I have rely no idea what I am doing wrong...
I want to access an value in the CodeBehind the easiest way possible I read I can to that whit ajax but I am not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use HTML5 + JavaScript + CSS with Office Add-ins; ASP.NET is not supported.  The only way you can use .NET languages is in any web services your add-in calls (such as using the ASP.NET Web API on the same web server that is hosting your add-in).

Comment: ok thanks than I will have to look for an other way to do what I want